# EF 6.1 Code First From Database - How to join

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework.  I've used the Code-First-From-Database approach to generate POCO for CUSTORDER and COLINE tables in the lawson database.  These two POCO look like below:  Note: I've removed most of the fields to make it easier to read.

```
[Table("LAWSON.CUSTORDER")]
public partial class CustOrder
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public short COMPANY { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ORDER_NBR { get; set; }

    public bool R_STATUS { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string ORDER_TYPE { get; set; }

    public DateTime ORDER_DATE { get; set; }
    public DateTime PRICE_DATE { get; set; }

    . . . 

}



[Table("LAWSON.COLINE")]
public partial class CoLine
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public short COMPANY { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ORDER_NUMBER { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int LINE_NBR { get; set; }

    public bool R_STATUS { get; set; }

    . . . 
}
```

When I use the DBContext to retrieve the CustOrder, I would like it to also include all the CoLine that are associated with the CustOrder.  I think I'll need to add below to the CustOrder class.

```
public virtual IList<CoLine> CoLines { get; set; }
```

But how can I tell EF to join these two table using the ORDER_NBR column in CustOrder to join ORDER_NUMBER in CoLine column?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not very clear.  I've edited my original question a bit.  What I did is changing the ORDER_NUM coulmn in CoLine to ORDER_NUMBER.  So, now I have a ORDER_NUM in CustOrder and a ORDER_NUMBER in CoLine that I would like to join.  How can I annotate the FK in a way that EF will know to join ORDER_NUM in CustOrder with ORDER_NUMBER in CoLine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`ForeignKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute on the FK property:

```
public class CustOrder
{

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("CoLines")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ORDER_NBR { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CoLine> CoLines { get; set; }
}
```

I also recommend  to change the navigation property type to `ICollection<T>`. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: so, FK annotation tells EF that it is the foreign key of CoLine table.  But how does EF knows that the ORDER_NBR in CustOrder is corresponding to ORDER_NBR in CoLine?  Is it because the column name are the same?  If so, what happen if their names happened to be different?

Comment: In that case use `Name` property of `Column` attribute to set the real name of that column in your Table: `Column(Order = 1, Name="ColumnName")`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not very clear. I've edited my original question a bit. What I did is changing the ORDER_NUM coulmn in CoLine to ORDER_NUMBER. So, now I have a ORDER_NUM in CustOrder and a ORDER_NUMBER in CoLine that I would like to join. How can I annotate the FK in a way that EF will know to join ORDER_NUM in CustOrder with ORDER_NUMBER in CoLine?

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth,

`public virtual IList<CoLine> CoLines { get; set; }`

is how you setup the nav property to the CoLine object from the CustOrder object.  Like octavioccl mentioned, you need to add the FK notation, however you would want this on the CoLine class I believe,  on the ORDER_NBR property.